# Require vendors in custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, composer

I'm building a plugin in which I would like to use a vendor library, but just adding it to the plugin's composer.json file doesn't seem to be enough to get it installed.

It works when I run composer update in the plugin's root dir but I was hoping there would be a way to have it automatically installed when the plugin is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include the library as required in your composer file, Craft will automatically download the package and install it in the global `vendor` directory rather than in your plugin directory (since both are inside the `vendor` folder).

You don't have to include it and you don't have to take care for certain other plugins that require the same one.

This process is done while running `composer install >>yourplugin<<` or `composer update` so everytime you make a Craft update it will search for new required libraries in your plugin but it won't do it during the installation of your plugin since every library should already exist - unless you add the dependency after your composer action -> `composer update` will solve it